# Question and answer sefer for shluchim

Tags: jewish-books, chabad, responsa

I remember hearing about a question and answer sefer that is written for Chabad Shulchim. It deals with various unique questions and answers that many shluchim will encounter during their shlichus. Does anyone happen to know what the name of sefer is and if there is a link for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly [Nesivim Bisdeh Hashlichus](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%28%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%29), by Dayan Levi Yitzchak Raskin of the London Beth Din.

Comment: Vols. 2 and 3 are available at https://seforimdeals.com/store15/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%94. Not sure about vol. 1.

Answer (score 3):

This was published in 1990. Aside from the two compilations directly from the Rebbe which both carried the title ספר השליחות, this was the first such publication from Kehot.

[image: Shlichus: Meeting the Outreach Challenge]

Comment: Looks good,tx....